# Unable to upload file to Google cloud storage using python - get a 404 error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying a upload a file to Google Cloud Storage via a python script but keep getting a 404 error! I am sure I am not trying to reference a non-available resource. My code snippet is:

```
uploadFile = open("testUploadFile.txt", "r")
httpObj = httplib.HTTPSConnection("googleapis.com", timeout = 10)
httpObj.request("PUT", requestString, uploadFile, headerString)
uploadResponse = httpObj.getresponse()
print "Request string is:" + requestString
print "Return status:" + str(uploadResponse.status)
print "Reason:" + str(uploadResponse.reason)
```

Where

```
requestString = /upload/storage/v1beta2/b/bucket_id_12345678/o?uploadType=resumable&name=1%2FtestUploadFile.txt%7Calm_1391258335&upload_id=AbCd-1234
headerString = {'Content-Length': '47', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a resumable upload, you'll need to start with a POST as described here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable

However, for a 47-byte object, you can use a simple upload, which will be much ... simpler.  Instructions are here:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#simple

It should be easy enough for you to replace the appropriate lines in your code with:

```
httpObj.request("POST", requestString, uploadFile, headerString)

requestString = /upload/storage/v1beta2/b/bucket_id_12345678/o?uploadType=media&name=1%2FtestUploadFile.txt%7Calm_1391258335
```

As an aside, in your code, headerString is actually a dict, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - will try this out. About the headerString, I just named the variable a string, I assumed specifying headers would be easier with a key-value association like dict, do I need to pass a string to the HTTPSConnection.request()?

Comment: HTTPSConnection.request does take a dict for the headers argument, so your code is correct.  I was just pointing out the name doesn't accurately reflect the type.

Comment: Just as followup - I cracked this problem by using python's Requests library. It really simplified things to a large extent for me. Thanks for the replies and comments - they were useful!